# Copy file from server share to local folder with Applescript

Tags: copy, applescript, directory

I have a folder on a server which is shared with guest access enabled.  I want to be able to copy a file from that folder to a local machine with Applescript.  So far I have:

```
property source : "server:sharedfolder:file.ext"
property destination : "Macintosh HD:Users:User:Documents:Folder"

tell application "Finder"
    copy file "source" to folder "destination"
end tell
```

Which I think should work.  But I get the error: Can't set folder source to destination number 10006.  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

you need to remove the quotes around your declared properties:

```
property source : "server:sharedfolder:file.ext"
property destination : "Macintosh HD:Users:User:Documents:Folder:"

tell application "Finder"
    copy file source to folder destination
end tell
```

It is also good practice to terminate your folder paths with a ":".

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Your current script reads: "Copy the **variable** `source` to the **variable** `destination`." I'm assuming you don't want to just change the variables around; you're using the wrong command. See my [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134568/copy-a-file-in-applescript/6588635#6588635) to learn more.