# Copy A File In AppleScript

Tags: file, copy, applescript, directory, move

I have the code below to set a variable in Applescript for the path to the iTunes Music Folder:

```
set username to text returned of (display dialog "RingtoneDude" default answer "Enter your path to your iTunes Ringtones folder here. e.g. /Users/David/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Ringtones" buttons {"Confirm", "Cancel"} default button 1)
```

And then I have the code to call the variable username to copy a file

```
tell application "Finder"
                copy file theCopy to username
            end tell
```

but the file theCopy which is on the desktop (theCopy is a variable) does not move to the folder.

Please help.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you've misunderstood the `copy` command. The `copy` command is used for transferring the contents of one variable into another variable. What you need to use is the `duplicate` command, which is used for copying **files**  to a specified location. Its syntax is as follows:

```
duplicate [alias] to [alias]
   [replacing boolean] --If true, replaces files in the destination with the same name
```

Having said that, your new code, in conjunction with Uriah Carpenter's answer, should look something like this:

```
set myRingtoneFolder to choose folder with prompt "Select your iTunes Ringtone folder:"
tell application "Finder" to duplicate theCopy to myRingtoneFolder
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you use [`choose folder`](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=AppleScript/2.1/en/as307.html) which returns an `alias`.

To make some text into an alias object use `set myAliasPath to myTextPath as alias`.

For more detailed information see [Aliases and Files](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_fundamentals.html) in the AppleScript documentation.